# Get all links in beautifulsoup tag from list comprehension

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all links within two specific classes using a nested list comprehension, but all my attempts aren't working. I can use the following to get the link in the first element, but what I'm not sure of how to do is get all links.  I can provide more detail if it's needed, but here's the code for getting the ith element.

```
[i.find(class_ = 'cta2 visit') for i in soup.find_all(class_ = 'buttons')][0]['href']
```

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: Not with the above, but I'm trying to get all elements not just the first one na dI'm not sure of how to do that.

Comment: Can you post the html you are parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
[i.find(class_='cta2 visit', href=True)['href'] for i in soup.find_all(class_='buttons')]
```

Comment: Thanks!  i realized one of the elemnets doesn't have a link, so i'm going to end up using an exception, but thanks anyway!

Comment: No need of try-except, check the edit. `href=True` will ignore all the tags that don't have hrefs hence won't result in throwing `KeyError`.